# loss data while try to use it in a function

Tags: powershell

My goal is to have all object data available in a function!

a function where following code

```
$_sw = (Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -Query "select * from sms_installedsoftware" | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -like $_SoftwareName})
```

is executed and returned to main contains everything that is expected. Due to unknown format of this object ( customObj or not ) guess I lose data while use wrong parameter type string[]

```
for ( $a=0; $a -lt $_sw.Count; $a++ ) {
     Write-Host ($_sw).ProductName[$a] ($_sw).ProductVersion[$a] ($_sw).InstalledLocation[$a] ($_sw).ProductCode[$a]
}
```

With example Input
`$_SoftwareName = "Java*"` expected Output is :

```
Java 8 Update 301 8.0.3010.9 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\
Java 8 Update 301 (64-bit) 8.0.3010.9 C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\
```

My function looks like this:

```
function listSWInformation {
        Param(
          [Parameter()]
          [string[]] $_Items
        )

       for ( $_a=0; $_a -lt $_Items.Count; $_a++ ) {
          Write-Host ($_Items).ProductName[$_a] ($_Items).ProductVersion[$_a] ($_Items).InstalledLocation[$_a] ($_Items).ProductCode[$_a]
       }
     }
```

Output is empty

The Object looking such :

```
SMS_InstalledSoftware (SoftwareCode = "{26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f32180301f0}")
SMS_InstalledSoftware (SoftwareCode = "{26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f64180301f0}")
```

May it helps what type I should use

Comment: `[string[]] $_Items` <- you're typing the input parameter as a _string_-array, causing PowerShell to convert the CIM instance objects to strings - and a string won't have the properties you're looking for :)

Comment: ok so which type is than correct ?

Comment: `[array]`, `[object[]]` or `[psobject[]]` would all work

Comment: Yes, array makes it possible - thank you

Comment: found following:  $_sw | Get-Member -MemberType Properties  which explores in detail the structure of this object if someone does not know like me

Comment: btw, your indexing strategy is suboptimal. You'll want to grab the property value of the `$a`'th object in the array, eg. `$_Items[$a].ProductName` rather than `$_Items.ProductName[$a]` - the latter is much slower and error prone

Comment: yes you were right i do not have only 1 $item that contains many Productnames instead of man $items were each has its own Productname - totally right